# How does Keras predict work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

So I'm training my neural network on closing prices and volumes of a commodity. I'm fully aware the approach is incredibly naive, it's purpose is it's meant to be. However I'm getting strange results from `model.predict`.

[my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE9CS.png)
The blue line is the training data and the orange what the model predicts the training data is with `model.predict_on_batch(training)`. It seems the model is trained well because the green line is the neural network running `model.predict_on_batch(validation)`.

However when I take the last value and run it through `model.predict` and then make a list by using the output of that as the next input for `model.predict` to make a future guess at stock prices I get the red line. It seems strange that's what the neural network predicts when it gets the validation set fairly right.

Both `model.predict` and `model.predict_proba` give the same result.

The main code is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/04f8f6022e93af0edad4cd6fbac118f2

How am I using the `model.predict` method wrong here?

Comment: It is better to not link your image, rather put it in the question itself and explain the issue with reference to that

Comment: It says I don't have enough rep for inline images. :(

Comment: oh really? I didn't know you needed to have some rep for inline images, sorry!